# Visual studio the following code is built without any error?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, build, compiler-errors

I have to link the [video](https://youtu.be/3tIqpEmWMLI?list=PLlrATfBNZ98dudnM48yfGUldqGD0S4FFb&t=553) related, but I will also add the code below.

How does this code builds without any error?

```
#define INTEGER Cherno

INTEGER Multiply(int a, int b){

INTEGER result = a * b;
return result;

}
```

When he hits `Ctrl+F7` and builds the code in visual studio, it builds without any error. What do I miss?

Thanks.

p.s : I know this code won't(at least should not) compile, I just wondered why it does in the case of the video owner.

Comment: you mean to return `result` don't you? I didn't look at the video...

Comment: I have no idea whether something about the way you've set up the project or about how you're using VS explains your observation, but I suspect so.  Certainly, the code presented is not a valid C (or C++) translation unit, and I would expect VS to complain if you tried to compile it as one.  I have no great regard for VS, but it does generally work.

Comment: What is `Cherno`?

Comment: @g19fanatic yes my bad, corrected.

Comment: @Michael it is just the name of the youtuber who owns the video I linked. The point is it is not valid but he builds it without error

Comment: He configured VS to compile to preprocessor output. But the actual build is using the previously successful obj generated earlier. Turn of both "Preprocess to a File" and "Preprocess Suppress Line Numbers" . Then build the project (F7). It should puke all over itself.

Comment: @WhozCraig hmm, ok, it makes sense. You can add this as answer if you wish and I'll accept it...

Answer (score 1):

you are returning `INTEGER`, not `result`. Even in the video as linked, he is returning `result`.

---

after the edit

In that video, he has a system with a preprocessor that adds additional includes at build-time to his code. He goes over this a few seconds after that link. `Cherno` must be defined somewhere in that included file.